# AWS RDS -how automated backups are generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I want to take automated backups in aws rds console what is the procedure for taking backup?

Comment: Can u add some code what u have tried then we can help you to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

- Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon RDS console
  at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.
- In the navigation pane, choose DB Instances, and then select the DB
  instance that you want to modify.
- Choose Instance Actions, and then choose Modify. The Modify DB
  Instance window appears.
- For Backup Retention Period, choose a number higher then 0 (0 =
  disable backups).
- Select Apply Immediately.
- Choose Continue.
- On the confirmation page, choose Modify DB Instance to save your
  changes and disable automated backups.

Something like this ?